# Does heat cream benefit the regeneration?

Tags: bodybuilding, blood-flow

I've been sick for the last two weeks and my doctor told me to get *Finalgon*, which is a heat cream. (Note: Finalgon is not only reacting with the skin, like some sticking plasters)

While I really liked the effect and it really benefited my curing, it felt like it was stimulating my blood circulation.

This made me curious, if there is any benefit using heat cream when it comes to regenerating from aching and sore muscles?

I do not want to question the effectiveness of heat creams in general, but if there is any value using it when trying to regenerate faster from hard workouts (which in my case is bodybuilding)? Maybe because of its stimulating effect?

I came up with this, as I regularly read about blood circulation aiding supplements and foods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I'll try to go though all possible explanations / answers.

Years ago there was a theory that muscle soreness comes from too much acid, produced by metabolism. That is not true. If trained enough - weakest fibers in muscles will be broken. That makes body reacting like on infection. So for that it would not help, since it is not an acid, causing the problem.

Better blood circulation is good to remove all that what is not needed, anyway. Also, as you wrote, it helps with providing substances that are needed to build up new, better, stronger fibers. However you need to have it in your body. I know that people are eating *Creatine* after training to better support regeneration. You can eat sugar since higher insulin level will move it to muscles first, then to liver, and if both are filled - to fat.

Question is how deep heating effect goes. We have heat detectors on skin level... I was using that heat creams like horse balm (since *Finalgon* is produced in Germany look for *Pferdebalsam*) and it went deep enough into my shoulder, but I don't think it can be effective for quadriceps / front of leg.

I don't know anyone who is using it that way, however I know runners who are taking hot bath after each training to speed up regeneration, and limit the pain. Perhaps that is better idea, more relaxing, less painful, and I believe - cheeper. :)

Comment: muscle sorrow ?

Comment: I think he meant __soreness__.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As for the, lets call it _depth of effect_, thats what I said when I wrote about the sticking plasters, that only react with the skin, mostly based on cinnamon and capsaicin.
I also know about the benefits of an alternating shower temperature and use it regularly as well. I will leave this question open for some time. If there is no other, maybe proved answer, I will accept yours.

Comment: Yes - I meant soreness. Thanks for clarification.